# Changing tar parameters

Tags: tar, archive, command

I'd like to change the command I'm actualy using to put files in a tar archive in order to achieve this:

1) Remove directories tree from the archive (actually the .tar.gz file mantains the tree of the files. I want the files to be "parent").

2) Remove the files used to create the archive and leave only the new .tar.gz

```
BACKUP_DEST=/home/backup/db/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`
tar -czvf ${BACKUP_DEST}/files.tar.gz ${BACKUP_DEST}
```

Comment: OK, so what's stopping you from doing so?  We're a question-and-answer site, and I'm not really seeing a question here.

Comment: I use this command in a cron job. I'd like to have the target .tar.gz file without directories tree and remove the original files used to create the archive. Automatically..

Comment: "remove the original files used to create the archive." Huh?

Comment: In /home/backup/db I have file "a", file "b" and file "c". I use tar to create /home/backup/db/files.tar.gz. When creating the archive I'd like to remove also ORIGINAL "a", "b" and "c".

Comment: So edit your question to include an actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tar` command has a little-known option named `--remove-files`, which is designed pretty much for this specific use-case.  There is a known bug in the interaction between `--remove-files` and `--append`, but since you don't appear to be using that, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :)
For the 1st question I found the -C command.. I tried with:

tar -czvf ${BACKUP_DEST}/files.tar.gz ${BACKUP_DEST} -C but a dummy archive is created..